# Can Word error rate help to analyze stammering?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, android-speech-api

I am making Android application that takes input audio. And detects stammering.

Can word error rate detect stammering? Java

Answer (score 0):

No, speech recognizers usually ignore speech defects since their goal is to recognize speech.

To model such things as well as hesitations you need a special grammar and specialized speech recognition model which is supported by some open source toolkits.